# Injecting a component in an aspect in a non-spring environment

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, aspectj

We have an aspect, named BusinessRuleAspect, in our code base that is used on the client side and on the server side of the project. On the server side we have spring, and the component is injected from the application context:

```
    <bean id="businessRuleAspect" class="com.fugro.gwf.domain.rules.aspects.BusinessRuleAspect" 
            factory-method="aspectOf">
            <property name="businessRuleManager" ref="businessRuleManager" />
    </bean>
```

The question: on the client side we don't have spring, what is the best way of injecting the businessRuleManager component in the aspect in such a case?

Comment: What do you mean on the client side?

Comment: You have asked the same lately on the AspectJ mailing list. Have you tried what Andy suggested to you? How was the outcome?

Comment: Yes, I just replied to Andy's latest message here:

Comment: http://aspectj.2085585.n4.nabble.com/Injecting-a-component-in-a-non-spring-environment-tc4651384.html#a4651388 
With 'client' I mean an Eclipse RCP application, talking to the server. 
This is an OSGI-based GUI, and because we had some trouble with the spring integration we decided to stop using it.
To be very precise: we had some trouble with the starting order of the bundles (spring extender/dynamic modules). Sometimes our GUI started OK, sometimes it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding the exact internals of what you are doing (or perhaps rather why), what you can do is something like the following in your aspect.  (Not the cleanest option, but at least a starting point)

If BusinessRuleManager is a singleton, how do you instantiate it/retrieve it from elsewhere in the non-Spring application?  Or is it used only within the aspect?

```
 after(PersistentObject persistentObject) :
persistentObjectPropertySetter(persistentObject)
        {

                if(businessRuleManager!=null)

                       businessRuleManager = BusinessRuleManager.getInstance();


                if(businessRuleManager!=null)
                {
                        businessRuleManager.execute(persistentObject,
thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
                }
        }
```

And in your BusinessRuleManager:

```
class BusinessRuleManager{
   .......
   static private BusinessRuleManager instance;

   static public BusinessRuleManager getInstance(){
     if( instance == null )
         instance = new BusinessRuleManager();

     return instance;
   }

   .......
}
```

This should allow you to use the mix of Spring injection as well as a non-spring container.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to your question: "If BusinessRuleManager is a singleton, how do you instantiate it/retrieve it from elsewhere in the non-Spring application?".
Here is the very concrete code that does it:

```
    BusinessRuleManager businessRuleManager = ContextInjectionFactory.make(BusinessRuleManagerImpl.class, context);
    context.set(BusinessRuleManager.class, businessRuleManager);
```

This construct puts an instance of our manager in the eclipse RCP context, ready to be injected in all kinds of other eclipse RCP components. This means that, borrowing your code we would get something like:

```
after(PersistentObject persistentObject) : persistentObjectPropertySetter(persistentObject) {
    if(businessRuleManager==null) {
            Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(BusinessRuleManager.class);
            BundleContext bundleContext = bundle.getBundleContext();
            IEclipseContext eclipseCtx = EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext(bundleContext);
            businessRuleManager = eclipseCtx.get(BusinessRuleManager.class);        
    }
    if(businessRuleManager!=null) {
        businessRuleManager.execute(persistentObject, thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

I tried to get it working, but failed miserably. The main problem is that the aspect lives in a domain module, which is shared between server and client. It's very difficult (and maybe even not desirable) to use the client side dependency injection framework ("RCP E4") in the shared code base of domain.